# How to convert a .m4v video/audio file to .mp4 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, video-conversion

Does Windows- 7 already have something that would convert `.m4v` to `.mp4`?

If not, how would I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In most cases, it's easy enough to just rename your file from `.m4v` to `.mp4`. There is no conversion needed.

Both `.m4v` and `.mp4` can be used as extensions for the [MPEG-4 Part 14 container format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14). While `.m4v` isn't used that often, `.m4a` is common for audio-only files.

There are two cases in which renaming does not work:

1. Sometimes, `.m4v` is also used as an extension for raw [MPEG-4 Part 2 video bitstreams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_2). In this case, renaming is not possible. The file has to be multiplexed into an `.mp4` container instead. This can be done, for example, with [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/): `ffmpeg -i input.m4v -c copy output.mp4`
2. When they originate from iTunes, `.m4v` files may be protected by Apple's DRM. In this case, renaming to `.mp4` is not possible, and you cannot convert the file itself either, as it is copyright-protected and can only be played with iTunes on the machine it was bought on.

In either case, it is not necessary to convert the file by re-encoding it. This would only deteriorate the video quality. It is certainly not necessary to buy some kind of video conversion software for this task either.

Comment: Indeed. The “v” is for video. It’s basically information just for humans. There’s also `m4a` for audio.

Comment: Yeah, typically you would name audio-only files `.m4a`. The iPhone uses `.m4r` for ringtones, for example.

Comment: I would add that extensions don't change the file, just how the computer decides to use it.

Comment: Mostly not even that. Because the file name is not truly metadata, it cannot be relied on. Instead, the presence of well-known/well-formed data is tested.

Comment: For those looking for useful information: `m4v` and `mp4` are not necessarily the same thing at all: an `m4v` file can be a pure data stream for burning directly to disc, without any metadata. In such cases, the file needs to be *packed* in an mp4 container before it can be played as file in a software video player. Even in 2016, this affects people why use, for instance, Adobe Media Encoder.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks, I know now what you mean, it may refer to MPEG-4 Part 2 video bitstream, which then has to be packed/multiplexed. I added this point to my answer.

Answer (score -2):

[Leawo total media converter](http://www.leawo.com/pro/total-media-converter-ultimate.html), or maybe [AVS Video converter](http://www.avs4you.com/AVS-Video-Converter.aspx)
They are both paid, but have free versions

Comment: I downvoted because there is no need to convert anything in the file. In fact, using such a conversion tool you mention would only deteriorate the quality of the contained audio/video by re-encoding it. (Good example of [generation loss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss))

Comment: Very true, free trials usually have their limitations. But I do not appear to have a downvote.. ?

Comment: That's not a matter of free trial vs. totally free or super expensive. You **do not need a conversion program**. Quite the contrary: you should avoid it, because they unnecessarily re-encode the audio and video parts (unless you know and find the option that does a stream copy, but not every tool has this). You received one upvoted, hence the 0 score.

Comment: Ah, Thank-you sir. I have become so used to converting all my videos that I kind of jumped the gun. Learn something new everyday, I guess.

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't actually explain why...with an explanation the OP would realise there is no need for an external program.

Comment: We appreciate your desire to help but as @slhck said in his answer, there is no conversion needed as the file format is the same across both extensions. I suggest you delete your answer since it doesn't add anything useful and only attracts downvotes.

Answer (score -2):

You can check this convertor out [WinxHD](http://www.winxdvd.com/hd-video-converter/), it's not free but you can easily work your way round and it facilitates m4v to mp4 or vice versa.

Hope I helped.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Can anyone tell me why is my answer downvoted!?

Comment: There is no need to convert anything at all (see above answer), and even more so, it's not worth paying for video conversion tools either when there are free alternatives.